# Can I use control's property in viewModel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Can i use a property of control like button in a viewmodel, for example if i have a button that content is "Hi", can I changing the content to "Bye" in the view model of the page?

Thanks

Comment: DataBinding, which is the backbone of the viewmodel pattern is made for that. Define a Text property in your viewmodel and bind the Content property of the button to the VM property. Don't forget to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Thankx for replying but I don't mean that thing, I meant can I run a controls function in VM?, actually i'm using <dxg:TreeListView and I want to use ExpandAllNodes() function in the VM.

Comment: What TreeListView control are you using? This doesn't sound like the vanilla TreeView.

Comment: I'm using devexpress treeListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use ExpandAllNodes() in your ViewModel. It is a function of the View and the ViewModel shouldn't know about the View.

Add a property (boolean?) to the ViewModel that indicates whether or not the Tree should be expanded and bind the state of the Tree to that property.

I am not quite sure what Treeview control you are using but is you cannot bind the state of the Treeview you could have a change of the property in the ViewModel cause a method call to expand the nodes.

Comment: I'm using devexpress treeListView, and i puted EventTrigger to the tree, and when I edit a specific row the tree collapsed automatically, and i set "true" to AutoExpandAllNodes.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel is basically for loose coupling between UI and logic of UI, And ViewModel doesn't know any things about UI. You can use binding to meet your requirement.